# Having issues with interactive-sections during autoinstall

Tags: system-installation, 22.04

I am trying to get the identity section of my user-data file to be interactive, however I am never prompted.  Here is my user-data file.

```
#cloud-config
interactive-sections:
 - identity
autoinstall:
  apt:
    disable_components: []
    geoip: true
    preserve_sources_list: false
    primary:
    - arches:
      - amd64
      - i386
      uri: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
    - arches:
      - default
      uri: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
  drivers:
    install: false
  identity:
    hostname: hostname
    password: password
    username: username
  kernel:
    package: linux-generic
  keyboard:
    layout: us
    toggle: null
    variant: ''
  locale: en_US.UTF-8
  network:
    ethernets:
      ens18:
        critical: true
        dhcp-identifier: mac
        dhcp4: true
        nameservers:
          addresses:
          - 1.1.1.1
          search:
          - domain.value
    version: 2
  ssh:
    allow-pw: true
    authorized-keys: []
    install-server: true
  storage:
    config:
    - ptable: gpt
      serial: 0QEMU_QEMU_HARDDISK_drive-scsi0
      path: /dev/sda
      wipe: superblock
      preserve: false
      name: ''
      grub_device: true
      type: disk
      id: disk-sda
    - device: disk-sda
      size: 1048576
      flag: bios_grub
      number: 1
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      type: partition
      id: partition-0
    - device: disk-sda
      size: 2147483648
      wipe: superblock
      flag: ''
      number: 2
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      type: partition
      id: partition-1
    - fstype: ext4
      volume: partition-1
      preserve: false
      type: format
      id: format-0
    - device: disk-sda
      size: 32209108992
      wipe: superblock
      flag: ''
      number: 3
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      type: partition
      id: partition-2
    - name: ubuntu-vg
      devices:
      - partition-2
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_volgroup
      id: lvm_volgroup-0
    - name: ubuntu-lv
      volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
      size: 16101933056B
      wipe: superblock
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_partition
      id: lvm_partition-0
    - fstype: ext4
      volume: lvm_partition-0
      preserve: false
      type: format
      id: format-1
    - path: /
      device: format-1
      type: mount
      id: mount-1
    - path: /boot
      device: format-0
      type: mount
      id: mount-0
  updates: security
  version: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `interactive-sections` under `autoinstall`.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  interactive-sections:
    - identity
...
```

By specifying `interactive-sections` you may get prompted for more than just identity.  You may need to confirm the disk layout and you'll likely have to manually reboot or shutdown when the installation is complete.  The reason is that [the installer will set its](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/f71de2e16d5fa99acd8c51beb00ee4423a9d783a/subiquity/server/server.py#L650) `interactive` flag.